# Pandas: Adding values of one column to another column if the date is different in datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a pandas dateframe like this where datetime column is index :

```
                         volume 
2018-04-08 15:52:26.110     43   
2018-04-08 15:53:26.110     17  
2018-04-08 15:54:26.110     10  
2018-04-09 12:40:35.877     15  
2018-04-09 12:41:35.877     16
```

My requirement is to add another column TotalVolume where it adds up the previous values but only when the dates are same. Desired Output:

```
                          volume  TotalVolume
2018-04-08 15:52:26.110     43        43
2018-04-08 15:53:26.110     17        57 (43+17)
2018-04-08 15:54:26.110     10        67 (57+10)
2018-04-09 12:40:35.877     15        15
2018-04-09 12:41:35.877     16        31 (15+16)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `cumsum` and `pd.Grouper`

This is the generalized way to accomplish this task and can be used for any frequency type: `Min`, `Hour`, `Week`, `BM`, `5H`, ...

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).cumsum()

                         volume
2018-04-08 15:52:26.110      43
2018-04-08 15:53:26.110      60
2018-04-08 15:54:26.110      70
2018-04-09 12:40:35.877      15
2018-04-09 12:41:35.877      31
```

---

```
df.assign(TotVol=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).cumsum())

                         volume  TotVol
2018-04-08 15:52:26.110      43      43
2018-04-08 15:53:26.110      17      60
2018-04-08 15:54:26.110      10      70
2018-04-09 12:40:35.877      15      15
2018-04-09 12:41:35.877      16      31
```

---

#### `groupby` and `df.index.date`

```
df.groupby(df.index.date).cumsum()
```

---

```
df.assign(TotVol=df.groupby(df.index.date).cumsum())
```

Answer (score 2):

you can group the dataframe by date and cummulative sumo of column will workk

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.groupby(df.index.date)['volume'].cumsum()
```